# Find out if the values of an object inside an array that is itself a value of a parent object are true

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, object

I am trying to validate information entered by a user and make sure none of the strings are empty.

Some of that information can be added into an array as "extra users" also joining the group.

So the data can look something like this:

```
const userInfo = {
  firstName: 'Jimmy',
  lastName: 'Hendrix',
  extraUsers: [{
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Michael'
  }],
};
```

And this is what I run to check for any empty strings in the 'extraUsers' Array:

```
function checkForEmptyStrings() {
  return (
    userInfo.extraUsers.every((extraUser) => {
      Object.values(extraUser).every((x) => x !== '')
    })
  );
}

console.log(checkForEmptyStrings())
```

The output I get is `false` but I'd expect it to be `true` since none of the strings are empty.
Actually if I console.log `Object.values(extraUser).every((x) => x !== '')` I get `true`

Why do I get `false` as a final result?

There's probably another way to do this, but for research purposes I'm curious to know what is going on here.

Cheers and happy coding

Comment: You're not returning the value to the outer `every`. Change it to parentheses or prepend `return` to `Object.values ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the inner `every`

```js
const userInfo = {
  firstName: 'Jimmy',
  lastName: 'Hendrix',
  extraUsers: [{
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Michael'
  }],
};
// And this is what I run to check for any empty strings in the 'extraUsers' Array:

function checkForEmptyStrings() {
  return (
    userInfo.extraUsers.every((extraUser) => {
      return Object.values(extraUser).every((x) => x )
    })
  );
}

console.log(checkForEmptyStrings())
```

Comment: Or more succinctly: `const checkForEmptyStrings = () => userInfo.extraUsers.every(extraUser => Object.values(extraUser).every(x => x));`

Comment: Cheers that was it! Thank you - I though there was implicit returns with every arrow function?

Comment: @MaxS. Only if the function body is an expression, not a block-statement `{ }`.